# Chess Game Winning Strategy

Tags: contest-math

Two players take turns placing kings on a $9 \times 9$ chessboard so that no king can capture another one. The player who cannot win this loses.

Is there a certain way to think about the problem?

Comment: Yes.  Think about symmetry.  One of the questions in my Related section is quite applicable.

Comment: @RossMillikan Sir, can you clarify more? Im not aware of it

Comment: @AngeloMark Try it with a $5 \times 5$ board first.

Answer (score 0):

The first player always wins.

The first player plays in the center, then follows the other player symmetrically (rotated $180^\circ$). If the other player can play, then the symmetric side can always be played as well, and the second player will runs out of moves eventually.